# Удаление get переменной

Tags: javascript

Стоит следующая задача, находясь на странице имеется n-ое количество get переменных, при нажатии на Del, необходимо остаться на данной странице, но удалить к примеру переменную name и соответственно ее значение. (адрес к примеру index?a=1&b=2&c=3&name=abc&vr=56).

Comment: А какие у вас наработки, покажите, что вы пытались сделать.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что не знаю как это реализовать

Comment: единственный вариант который сейчас в уме, это разбить в php адрес explode

Comment: "Оставаясь на странице" - нельзя. Не перегружаясь можно только `#` часть менять, но она не передаётся на сервер. Можно куки менять. А часть урла при `?` нельзя. Можно при переходе вместо post/get делать переход на другой урл. В новых браузерах "хвост" скрывается. Какая у вас первоначальная задача? Возможно эту задачу нужно решать другим способом.

Comment: хорошо тогда можно рассмотреть вариант исключить из URL и загрузить тот же URL без переменной,  но опять же вопрос как?

Comment: Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, то будьте добры, нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом и на треугольник вверх. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменять URL находясь на той же странице можно при помощи History API, всё остальное - дело программной логики:

```
let params={},
order=[]
location.search.replace(/^\?/,'').split('&').forEach(pie=>{
    let [k,v]=pie.split('=')
    params[k]=v
    order.push(k)
})
$(document).keydown(e=>{
    if(!e.which==46||!order.length) return
    delete params[order.pop()]
    console.log(params)
    window.history.replaceState('','',location.origin+(order.length?'/?'+order.reduce((prev,cur)=>prev.concat(cur+'='+params[cur]),[]).join('&'):''))
})
```

Получать доступ к get переменным в этом примере вы можете через объект `params`.
Если нужно разжевать написанное, то скажите, могу сдобрить код комментариями.